# count string value using map in javascript, return NaN

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am trying to use a map to count duplicate string number in an array,
my code:

```
var map = {};
var myarray = ["John", "John", "John", "Doe", "Doe", "Smith",
               "John", "Doe", "Joe"];

for (var a = 0; a < myarray.length; a++) {
    if (map[myarray[a]] !== null) {
        map[myarray[a]] += 1;
    } else {
        map[myarray[a]] = 1;
    }
}
```

but when I do `console.log(map);` it returns

```
Object {John: NaN, Doe: NaN, Smith: NaN, Joe: NaN}
```

Why it is NaN?
I want to have the result like:

```
John :4, Doe: 3, Smith: 1, Joe: 1
```

How can I do?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should not comapre with `null` strictly `===` because `undefined` is not equivalent to `null`. Try this:

```
if (map[myarray[a]] != null) {
```

or simply:

```
if (map[myarray[a]]) {
```

Comment: if (map[myarray[a]]) or map[myarray[a]] !== undefined works, thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 1):

`map[myarray[a]] !==null` will return true when the field is `undefined`, which is the case when first time encountering a new value.

Should be:

```
map[myarray[a]] !== undefined
```

or

```
map[myarray[a]] != null
// undefined == null
```